# issue compiling prepare statement while updating mysql table

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have created a form to fill data into a MySQL table, using JSP. In the update part, when I enter data with the intended primary key value and hit the submit button, it's doing nothing am just getting a blank page.

I am fairly new in java programming Please help.

```
<%
//jsp prog for database connection
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;

try {

        String candidate = request.getParameter("candidate");

       // So on....

            Connection conn=ConnectionProvider.getConn();  


        int updateQuery = 0;

        if(candidate!=null && phone!=null && recname!=null && ofrdate!=null &&     ofrstat!=null && ofrdctc!=null && DOJ!=null && month!=null && jngstat!=null)
        {

            if(candidate!="" && phone!="" && recname!="" && ofrdate!="" && ofrstat!="" && ofrdctc!="" && DOJ!="" && month!="" && jngstat!="")
            {
               String queryString =("UPDATE mytable SET recname=?,ofrdate=?,ofrstat=?,ofrdctc=?,DOJ=?,month=?,jngstat=? WHERE phone=?");

                pstatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

                pstatement.setString(1, phone);

                pstatement.setString(2, recname);

                pstatement.setString(3, ofrdate);

                pstatement.setString(4, ofrstat);

                pstatement.setString(5, ofrdctc);

                pstatement.setString(6, DOJ);

                pstatement.setString(7, month);

                pstatement.setString(8, jngstat);

                updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
        }  // end 



    } // end of try
    // catch exception block
    // finally block
%>
```

Comment: First off does it compile at all? I'm referring to your way of  declaring the queryString variable and the curly braces between if and else statement in the lower half.

Comment: it does compile without any warning or error n moves to form page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
String queryString =("UPDATE mytable SET recname=?,ofrdate=?,ofrstat=?,ofrdctc=?,DOJ=?,month=?,jngstat=? WHERE phone=?");

pstatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

pstatement.setString(1, phone);

pstatement.setString(2, recname);

pstatement.setString(3, ofrdate);

pstatement.setString(4, ofrstat);

pstatement.setString(5, ofrdctc);

pstatement.setString(6, DOJ);

pstatement.setString(7, month);

pstatement.setString(8, jngstat);
```

There is no correspondence between your wild cards and your `pstatement.setString(int, String);` , you should set them in the order they appear in your query string.

For instance the first wild card refers to the `recname` field, but you set it to: `pstatement.setString(1, phone);`

Probably that's why the update fails.

Try setting the wild cards sequentially starting from the String `recname` onwards with the 8th one set to the String `phone` :

```
pstatement.setString(1, recname);

pstatement.setString(2, ofrdate);

pstatement.setString(3, ofrstat);

pstatement.setString(4, ofrdctc);

pstatement.setString(5, DOJ);

pstatement.setString(6, month);

pstatement.setString(7, jngstat);

pstatement.setString(8, phone);
```

Comment: @pradyu glad that helped. I saw you are fairly new: would you mind to mark the answer as accepted? I would appreciate that and it would be helpful for others with a similar issue